# How do you calculate a perspective projection matrix?

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, projection-matrix

Right now I have the ability to scale, rotate, and translate points by using a matrix.

[image]

```cpp
// I use a left to right multiplying style (scale, rotate, then translate)
Matrix model = Matrix::Scale(0.4f) * Matrix::Rotation(45.0f, Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)) * Matrix::Translation(Vector3(0.0f, 0.5f)).Transposed();
```

```c
// vertex shader code
#version 460 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition;

uniform mat4 model;

void main() {
    gl_Position = model * vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0);
}
```

The main problem I'm having is creating a perspective projection matrix.

```cpp
static Matrix Projection(float verticalFoV, float aspectRatio, float zNear, float zFar) {
        // is this even correct?
        float yScale = (1.0f / tan(verticalFoV / 2.0f)) * aspectRatio;
        float xScale = yScale / aspectRatio;
        float frustumLength = zFar - zNear;

        return Matrix({
            xScale, 0, 0, 0,
            0, yScale, 0, 0,
            0, 0, -((zFar + zNear) / frustumLength), -((2.0f * zNear * zFar) / frustumLength),
            0, 0, -1.0f, 0
        });
    }
```

Which would then be used like this.

```cpp
Matrix projection = Matrix::Projection(70.0f * DegreesToRadians, screenWidth / screenHeight, 0.1f, 100.0f);
```

I send over the matrices without transposing them.

```cpp
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "model"), 1, false, &model[0][0]);
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "projection"), 1, false, &projection[0][0]);
```

And I want to be able to multiply them left to right in the vertex shader.

```c
#version 460 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main() {
    // I'm eventually gonna add view so it'd look like this
    // gl_Position = model * view * projection * vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0);
    gl_Position = model * projection * vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0);
}
```

P.S: I want to use a left handed coordinate system. (Right = +X, Up = +Y, Forward = +Z)

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL matrices are stored with column major order. Your matrices are stored with row major order. Hence, you have to multiply the matrices to the vector form the right:

<s>`gl_Position = model * projection * vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0);`</s>

```c
gl_Position = vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0) * model * projection;
```